# Why am I getting the error **'TypeError "message" is read-only'** after rendering images from a react app code while using codesandbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

I was using codesandbox (the online code editor/sandbox) to build a react app that would render 3 online-sourced images. But it has been difficult to make it work and display these images.

It has a stylesheet applied to it with minimal styles for testing and practice.

I keep getting the error **`TypeError "message" is read-only`** on the browser preview page.

I have searched through stackoverflow, google and online but still unable to solve the issue.

**Below is the content of the wrong ***index.js*** Code file**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1>My Favourte Foods</h1>
    <div>
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/268533/pexels-photo-268533.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-268533.jpg"
      >
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
      >
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg"
      >
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After many unsuccessful searches, I finally figured out the issue and fixed the problem. Hence, I feel I should share the experience.

The problem was that the image (img) tag as a self-closing tag was not properly closed and perhaps should always be properly closed while working with react. Hence, was giving that error message.

For instance, `<img src...>` is wrong and not properly closed. instead you should use;

`<img src..../>` This is correct and properly closed. In other words, the closing forward slash should accompany a self-closing tag like an **img** tag.

**Below is the correct/rectified code file (Image tags are properly closed with forward slash at the ending tag)**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1>My Favourte Foods</h1>
    <div>
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/268533/pexels-photo-268533.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-268533.jpg" />
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" />
      <img
        className="srcimgimg"
        src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>, document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no syntax errors. I had the same issue but I was doing a simple challenge for template literals and manipulating strings. I had an extra semicolon (;) inside of a statement that I copied and pasted to.

ex. console.log(attraction.toLowerCase(););

As soon as I removed the semicolon, the code ran as expected.